# grails 2.4.4 @Resource gives 404 for all URLS

Tags: rest, grails

I am struggling to know how to implement REST in grails.  the [documentation](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/webServices.html#REST) says I should be able to do the following:

User.groovy

```
import grails.rest.*
@Resource(uri='/users')
class User {
  // lots of stuff
}
```

UserController.groovy

```
class UserController {
static scaffold = true;
}
```

Basically, if I try any of the following URLS, I always get 404:

```
 http://localhost:8080/myapp/users/
 gives: HTTP Status 404 - "/players/index.gsp" not found.

 http://localhost:8080/myapp/users/1
 gives: 404, the requested resource is not available (I have users defined in bootstrap)
```

NOTE:

1. I also tried it with the scaffolding line commented out.
2. .../myapp/user does work, but gives the HTML page
3. Even if @Resource did work, it is not actually what I am looking for.  I need custom logic for each method.  I have found lots of documented different ways to do this in 2.3, but don't know if this is still the correct way for 2.4?

Comment: Try running `grails url-mappings-report` to see if it's mapped but using an unexpected pattern, or not mapped at all

Comment: @burt, that grails command is a great tip!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a working solution:

1. Remove the @Resource(uri='/users') line
2. Add the line: "/users"(resources:"user") to the file: urlMappings.groovy.

Et voila, works as it should have with the @Resource annotation, no other changes required.

I can only assume there is a bug in Resources annotation, or that it only works if you have no controller already defined or similar.